# Why is access denied when using the Unified Write Filter on Windows 10 IoT?

Tags: microsoft-windows-iot

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise IoT 64-bit and am trying to run the following command in the command prompt:

```
uwfmgr.exe get-config
```

The result is always "The command failed (Access is denied.)." whether using admin rights or not. Somebody else has helped me disable some settings on the PC. It needs locking down for security reasons, but I still need to be able to run this command. Any ideas for how this could happen and what the fix is?

Comment: This does not appear to be a common program (at least I do not see it here - my own or client machines).  Where is the program located?  Standard program in Program Files?  This folder is restricted.

Comment: @John It is only located on a Windows Embedded IOT machine. If you're not using that machine, you won't find it.

Comment: Try to run first `uwfmgr servicing enable`. Run as admin.

Comment: @harrymc Tried it. Access still denied when running as admin and when entering both "uwfmgr" and "uwfmgr.exe"

Answer (score 1):

The following articles covers UWF exclusions. [Write filter exclusions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwfexclusions).

Based on our findings, the UWF exclusion `c:\windows\system32\config`, being present will cause this issue.

If removing the exclusion, with the command `uwfmgr` file remove-exclusion `c:\windows\system32\config` and then restarting the issue will likely be resolved.