# Why is access denied when using UWF on Windows 10 Embedded IoT?

Tags: microsoft-windows-iot

I have a PC that uses Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit and have had some help from an external company to convert it to a Windows Embedded machine. One thing I need to do on the PC is use UWF to check the volume settings of the PC.

There are two accounts on the PC: A standard account and an administrator account. When running the following command in a command prompt on the admin account, UWF successfully returns the information I need it to:

```
uwfmgr.exe get-config
```

When I do this with the standard account, I get an error:

```
The command failed (Access is denied.).
```

This happens with a normal command prompt and when running the command prompt as administrator. The external company must have disabled a particular feature that has prevented this command from working. But what could this feature be? What is a common cause for this kind of issue?

Comment: Why have you posted this again? Your earlier question has been migrated here https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/4674/746 if you want to update the question please edit that one.

Comment: Hi Ben, as hardillb notes, the moderators of Super User moved your previous question here. You should be able to edit and update that one instead. Sorry about the confusion!